# Compare Column A to Column B and copy items that are in both columns into Column C

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have two columns each containing a list of URLs (over 50,000), some of which are duplicates. A screenshot with simplified URLs: http://tinypic.com/r/nevmzn/8.

Note that the first row has two URLs that are slightly different but each contain the same domain: `www.apple.com` and `http://www.apple.com` direct to the same site, therefore the third column should reflect that.

Is there a way where I can set it up where the third column (both Columns) will automatically sort which URLs are duplicates and which aren't?
Is there a formula I could use, or an Excel feature that will help me automatically do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to strip the http:// part from the comparison, you can use

=IF(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"http://","")=SUBSTITUTE(B1,"http://",""),SUBSTITUTE(B1,"http://",""),"no")

Answer (score 0):

You can use `=IF(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1))=RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-FIND(".",B1)),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)),"No")`

`=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1))` will return `website.com` from a cell even if it starts with `http://` or `http://www.` or `www.`

The above formula just compares the website from each column and if it is a match, it will return the website, otherwise return "No"